# Fetch specific iPhone application data from Apple iTunes

Tags: iphone, xml, rss, itunes

I need an script that can fetch data from a link like this:

http://itunes.apple.com/app/monopoly/id337021781

Image, date added ... etc

and return it JSON or XML. I see that there are a solution for top 10 apps but it wont help me.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=10/xml

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=337021781

here's the documentation: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html